# Performant 2D Grid Cluster Finder Algorithm

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, array, computational-geometry

I would like to vastly improve the speed of the second part of this algorithm to find clusters of points on a 2D grid.

Each point is represented by a `Region` on the grid (which is the same idea as a `Range` in Excel, just renamed here to not conflict with `System.Range`. In future iterations of the code, the concept of a "point" may be expanded to a range of cells on the grid which is why its not just an x,y coordinate.)

Each cluster of points is represented by a `Container` class that holds the region on the grid where that container exists along with a list of the points that can be found inside that `Container`.

The first part of the code performs a Depth-First Search of each point to find other points that are within 1 cell in any of the 8 directions of that point, and does so until it finds a contiguous cluster of points. This first part of the code is lightning fast but it does not find all the containers I'm looking for.

I want each container to have an empty boundary around it, meaning the cells around that container do not overlap any other points or containers.

The DFS algorithm only looks at the cells immediately around each point inside the container, so you end up with situations like this (dark blue cells are points and light blue cells are the other cells in the container):

[image]

Since there were no points in the container near the point outside the container, then the DFS algorithm does not merge it in with the container.

So to overcome this, `Part 2` in the code below (which can be turned on or off to see the speed difference) loops through each container and sees if its boundary cells overlap any other containers and merges the ones that do. (The code below can consider a 1-cell boundary or a 2-cell boundary by changing the `expandBoundaryBy` parameter value which will be needed in future iterations of the code base as well.)

This fixes the DFS problem mentioned above but it slows the algorithm down tremendously.

There are two options in `Part 2` of the code for finding these overlapping containers but they are both very slow.

My goal is to have the entire algorithm run lightning fast like the first part of it does (with the DFS algorithm).

I would like to avoid any external libraries.

Maybe there is a much more obvious way to find these clusters of points on a grid that I'm not thinking of. I've looked at R-Trees, sweep line algorithms, and others but can't seem to find a solution that runs fast for large grids (e.g. 10,000 x 10,000 grids. The DFS algorithm finishes in 5-10 seconds on grids that size).

Here is the working code with a small bit of LINQPad-specific syntax to make it easy to test the code by displaying an HTML table representing the points and containers on the grid.

```
void Main()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Can add numbres into this array to test grids of different sizes
    (new int[] { 100 }).ToList().ForEach(size => {
        var va = Array.CreateInstance( typeof( bool ), new[] { size, size }, new[] { 1, 1 } );
        var grid = (bool[,])va;
        List<Region> filledCells = new List<Region>();
        var pa = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(bool), new[] { size, size }, new[] { 1, 1 });
        var points = (bool[,])pa;
        
        // Randomly setting points
        for (int row = 1; row <= size; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 1; column <= size; column++)
            {
                var value = random.NextDouble() < 0.09; 
                grid[row, column] = value;
                if(grid[row,column])
                {
                    filledCells.Add(new Region(row,column));
                }
                
            }
        }

        stopwatch.Start();
        
        // Create the GridContainerFinder instance
        GridContainerFinder finder = new GridContainerFinder();
        var containers = finder.FindCellContainers(filledCells, grid);
        
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Size: {size}x{size}, Containers: {containers.Count}, Filled Cells: {filledCells.Count}, Time: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        
        if (size <= 100) // Grids that are too large take a long time to display in LINQPad
        {
            Util.RawHtml(GetGridHtml(grid, containers)).Dump($"Grid {size}x{size}");  // LINQPad-specific method to dump HTML
        }
        
        stopwatch.Reset();
        
    });
}

public record struct Region(int TopRow, int LeftColumn, int BottomRow, int RightColumn)
{
    public int TopRow { get; init; } = TopRow;
    public int LeftColumn { get; init; } = LeftColumn;
    public int BottomRow { get; init; } = BottomRow;
    public int RightColumn { get; init; } = RightColumn;

    public Region(int topRow, int leftColumn) : this(topRow, leftColumn, topRow, leftColumn) { }
}

public static class RegionHelpers
{
    public static bool Overlaps(this Region region, Region otherRegion, int expandBoundaryBy, int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {
        // Manually expand the region
        var expandedTopRow = Math.Max(region.TopRow - expandBoundaryBy, 1);
        var expandedLeftColumn = Math.Max(region.LeftColumn - expandBoundaryBy, 1);
        var expandedBottomRow = Math.Min(region.BottomRow + expandBoundaryBy, rowCount);
        var expandedRightColumn = Math.Min(region.RightColumn + expandBoundaryBy, columnCount);

        // Check for overlap with the expanded container
        if (otherRegion.TopRow > expandedBottomRow || expandedTopRow > otherRegion.BottomRow)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (expandedLeftColumn > otherRegion.RightColumn || otherRegion.LeftColumn > expandedRightColumn)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public class Container
{
    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public List<Region> FilledCells { get; set; } = new List<Region>();
    
    public Container(Region region)
    {
        Region = region;
    }

    public void Add(int row, int col)
    {
        Region = new Region(Math.Min(Region.TopRow, row), Math.Min(Region.LeftColumn, col), Math.Max(Region.BottomRow, row), Math.Max(Region.RightColumn, col));
        FilledCells.Add(new Region(row,col));
    }

    public void Merge(Container other)
    {
        Region = new Region(Math.Min(this.Region.LeftColumn, other.Region.LeftColumn), Math.Max(this.Region.RightColumn, other.Region.RightColumn), Math.Min(this.Region.TopRow, other.Region.TopRow), Math.Max(this.Region.BottomRow, other.Region.BottomRow));
        FilledCells.AddRange(other.FilledCells);
    }

    public List<Region> AllCells(int rowCount, int columnCount, int expandBy = 0)
    {
        var topRow = Math.Max(1, Region.TopRow - expandBy);
        var bottomRow = Math.Min(rowCount, Region.BottomRow + expandBy);
        var leftColumn = Math.Max(1, Region.LeftColumn - expandBy);
        var rightColumn = Math.Min(columnCount, Region.RightColumn + expandBy);
        
        var rows = Enumerable.Range(topRow, bottomRow - topRow + 1).ToArray();
        var cols = Enumerable.Range(leftColumn, rightColumn - leftColumn + 1).ToArray();

        return rows.SelectMany(row => cols.Select(col => new Region(row, col))).ToList();
    }

    public List<Region> GetBoundaryCells(int rowCount, int columnCount, int expandBy = 1)
    {
        // Initialize list to hold the border cells.
        HashSet<Region> borderCells = new HashSet<Region>();

        // Calculate the expanded boundaries of the this.
        int topRowExpanded = Math.Max(this.Region.TopRow - expandBy, 1);
        int leftColumnExpanded = Math.Max(this.Region.LeftColumn - expandBy, 1);
        int bottomRowExpanded = Math.Min(this.Region.BottomRow + expandBy, rowCount);
        int rightColumnExpanded = Math.Min(this.Region.RightColumn + expandBy, columnCount);

        // Loop through each cell within the expanded boundaries.
        for (int row = topRowExpanded; row <= bottomRowExpanded; row++)
        {
            for (int col = leftColumnExpanded; col <= rightColumnExpanded; col++)
            {
                // If the cell is not inside the original cluster boundaries, it's a border cell.
                if (!(row < 1 || col < 1 || row > rowCount || col > columnCount) && (row < this.Region.TopRow || row > this.Region.BottomRow ||
                    col < this.Region.LeftColumn || col > this.Region.RightColumn))
                {
                    borderCells.Add(new Region(row, col));
                }
            }
        }

        return borderCells.Except(AllCells(rowCount, columnCount)).ToList();
    }

    public void Merge(List<Container> otherContainers)
    {
        if (otherContainers.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var topRow = Math.Min(this.Region.TopRow, otherContainers.Min(oc => oc.Region.TopRow));
        var leftColumn = Math.Min(this.Region.LeftColumn, otherContainers.Min(oc => oc.Region.LeftColumn));
        var bottomRow = Math.Max(this.Region.BottomRow, otherContainers.Max(oc => oc.Region.BottomRow));
        var rightColumn = Math.Max(this.Region.RightColumn, otherContainers.Max(oc => oc.Region.RightColumn));

        Region = new Region(topRow, leftColumn, bottomRow, rightColumn);

        FilledCells.AddRange(otherContainers.SelectMany(oc => oc.FilledCells));
    }
    public bool Overlaps(Container otherContainer, int expandBoundaryBy, int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {
        return Region.Overlaps(otherContainer.Region, expandBoundaryBy, rowCount, columnCount);
    }
}

class GridContainerFinder
{

    public List<Container> FindCellContainers(List<Region> filledCells, bool[,] grid)
    { 
        int rowCount = grid.GetLength(0);
        int columnCount = grid.GetLength(1);

        // PART 1
        // Get initial set of containers using DFS (very fast on large grids)
        var ca = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Container), new[] { rowCount, columnCount }, new[] { 1, 1 });
        var containersGrid = (Container[,])ca;
        
        List<Container> containers = new List<Container>();

        foreach (var filledCell in filledCells)
        {
            if(containersGrid[filledCell.TopRow, filledCell.LeftColumn] != null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            Container newContainer = new Container(filledCell);
            
            Dfs(grid, containersGrid, filledCell.TopRow, filledCell.LeftColumn, newContainer);
            containers.Add(newContainer);
        }

        // PART 2
        var runPart2 = true;
        if(runPart2)
        {
            // Merge overlapping containers (very slow on large grids)
            bool hasMerged;
            do
            {
                hasMerged = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < containers.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    var container1 = containers[i];
                    HashSet<Container> overlappedContainers = new HashSet<Container>();

                    // Option 1 (very slow)
                    //container1.GetBoundaryCells(rowCount, columnCount, 1).ForEach(bc =>
                    //{
                    //  if(gridContainerPoints[bc.TopRow, bc.LeftColumn] != null)
                    //  {
                    //      overlappedContainers.Add(gridContainerPoints[bc.TopRow, bc.LeftColumn]);
                    //  }
                    //});               
                    
                    // Option 2 (slow)
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < containers.Count; j++)
                    {
                        var container2 = containers[j];
                        
                        if (container1.Overlaps(container2,1,rowCount,columnCount))
                        {
                            overlappedContainers.Add(container2);
                        }
                    }

                    if(overlappedContainers.Count > 0)
                    {               
                        // Merge ovrerlapped containers into container1 and remove overlapped containers
                        container1.Merge(overlappedContainers.ToList());
                        containers.RemoveAll(c => overlappedContainers.Contains(c));

                        // Update gridContainerPoints
                        foreach (var cell in container1.AllCells(rowCount, columnCount))
                        {
                            containersGrid[cell.TopRow, cell.LeftColumn] = container1;
                        }

                        hasMerged = true;
                    }

                    if (hasMerged) break;
                }
            } while (hasMerged);
        }

        return containers;
    }

    private int[,] directions = new int[8, 2] {
        {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1},
        {0, -1}, {0, 1},
        {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}
    };
    
    private void Dfs(bool[,] grid, Container[,] containersGrid, int row, int col, Container container)
    {
        int rows = grid.GetLength(0);
        int cols = grid.GetLength(1);

        if (row < 1 || row > rows || col < 1 || col > cols || !grid[row, col] || containersGrid[row, col] != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        containersGrid[row, col] = container;
        
        container.Add(row, col);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Dfs(grid, containersGrid, row + directions[i, 0], col + directions[i, 1], container);
        }
    }
}

private static string GetGridHtml(bool[,] grid, List<Container> containers = null)
{
    var html = "<table>";
    for (int row = grid.GetLowerBound(0); row < grid.GetUpperBound(0) + (grid.GetLowerBound(0) == 0 ? 0 : 1); row++)
    {
        html += "<tr>";
        for (int column = grid.GetLowerBound(1); column < grid.GetUpperBound(1) + (grid.GetLowerBound(1) == 0 ? 0 : 1); column++)
        {
            var color = "white";
            if(containers != null)
            {       
                foreach (var container in containers)
                {
                    if (row >= container.Region.TopRow && row <= container.Region.BottomRow && column >= container.Region.LeftColumn && column <= container.Region.RightColumn)
                    {
                        color = "lightblue";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (grid[row, column])
            {
                color = "blue";
            }
            html += $"<td style='background-color: {color}; width: 10px; height: 10px;'></td>";
        }
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>";

    return html;
}
```

Comment: Typical ways to identify connected components: [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), and [morphological thickening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinning_(morphology)#Thickening). Let's focus on the 2nd one. Allocate a shadow grid. You have already assigned a single Container ID to each Point. Visit every point, and in the 1- or 2-neighborhood of the point write its container ID to the shadow grid, first verifying the grid cell is empty. In the case of collision, we have identified that container A needs to be known henceforth as container B -- they touch, and B swallows it.